# how to get userId from token in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I create API in django with `django-rest-framework`. I have a model called `Comment`, and each `Comment` has a `UserId`. I am creating the users by `rest-auth.` Each `User` has a token which I use on frontend.

```py
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Comment(models.Model):
    CommentId= models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    DataCreated = models.DateField(default=now, editable=False)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('CommentId', 'DataCreated', 'UserId', 'Name')
```

I create a simpre view which save new Comment

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def addComment(request):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The point is that in `request.data` I receive data like `Name` and `Token` and not `UserId`, so I am wondering how to get `UserId` from `Token`?

Comment: Can't you send the userId aswell when you're making a request?

Comment: I would prefer not, unless there is not other option

Comment: when you say you are receiving data like "name" is it name from comment or user class?

Comment: It is a nam of a Comment . I meant that I reace the data in json with Name and Token, instead of Name and UserId as it is defined in my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user, I dont remeber the nickname, wrote here the answer which was right but I didn't understand well, because I just dont know yet well how to work with api.

so I copy the answer

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication

@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def addComment(request):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(UserId=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
     'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ],
}
```

and when sendind the request, you need to add in header `Authorization: Token ${token}` (I didnt know that that´s why I was getting an error)